# replacement for on in Jquery 2

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery 2.0.2 but for some reason "on" doesn't seem to be working on elements added by jquery . below is an example where the second part isn't working

```
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="hi">Danger</button>
            <div id="edit-form">
            </div>



    <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#test1').on('click',function(){
       $('#edit-form').html('<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="test2">Info</button>');
    })
     //this part doesn't work \/
    $('#test2').on('click',function(){
      alert('test');
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: you need to delegate an event cause your element is added from code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This has nothing to do with jQuery 2.x; it's the same in jQuery 1.x)*

The way you're using it will only hook the event on elements that exist **when you run your code**. Since `#test2` doesn't, it doesn't get hooked.

You have two options:

1. Hook it after you add it

   ```
   $('#test1').on('click',function(){
       $('#edit-form').html('<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="test2">Info</button>');
       $('#test2').on('click',function(){
         alert('test');
       })
   })
   ```
2. Use event delegation:

   ```
   $('#test1').on('click',function(){
       $('#edit-form').html('<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="test2">Info</button>');
   })
   $(document).on("click", "#test2", function() {
       alert('test');
   });
   ```

   That works by actually hooking the `click` event on `document`, but then only firing your handler if the event passed through an element matching `#test2` (and it calls your handler with `this` set to that matching element, as usual). You don't have to use `document`; any ancestor element of `#test2` would work (including `#edit-form`).